# Are these remains of electricity meter's anti-tampering seal?

Tags: electrical-panel, utilities

This is an electricity meter on top of an old Zinsco panel. The meter does not have anything else hanging that reminds me of an anti-tamper seal. So I am wondering - has anyone tampered with this electricity meter?

[image]

**If it is anti-tampering device, then are there any fines against homeowner? Should I try to track down the person who did this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Sure" - "You can assume yes" - However this **does NOT mean** someone tampered with it.

Someone has not secured the meter with a new identifying marker that gives a power company or service person indication that no one has touched it since it was last secured.

This doesn't mean it was tampered with, it means as I've noted, someone did not re-secure it.

Comment: Is there a difference from electricity provider's point of view? Is there a fine if, for example, one of the construction workers we hired in the past have messed with it?

Comment: @HansSolo That's a question for your utility, as there is likely no universal response to that question.

Comment: It depends on where you live, and what (if anything) they want to do about it. Basically, safety & theft are the concerns. If there is evidence of either & the power compnay or some official chooses to make an issue, they will investigate. But more than likely, they will re-tag it when around next. If you know nothing was done that wasn't supposed to be, you shouldn't need to worry.

Comment: ps.... you could always call them and ask them to tag it

Comment: **Should I try to track down the person who did this?** How would you possibly do that? Unless you have video evidence, anyone who you **think** did it (handyman, angry neighbor, whatever...) will deny it.